# Clones replace previous app on my iPhone Device and simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, rename, cloning

I have created 4 clones of my app. First one was named as iPhoneApp. When I execute my app first time, it is installed on my device. Then when I try to execute any of my clone, it replaces my older app and get installed with same name i.e iPhoneApp.

I have renamed the my clones and their project files but still i get same name every time for all clones. I am changing names like this:
[image]

But still when I execute this one, I get same old name for package. How i can change it so that all my clones get installed separately.

Answer (score 2):

It is the **bundle identifier** of an app that determines whether an app is unique. If all of your app 'clones' have the same bundle identifier, then they will all overwrite one another when you try to install. By default, the name of the app on the home screen is the name of the *target* that you build.

Select your project in the left hand navigator in Xcode, and then select your Target from the list. You should see your bundle identifier on the right. If you want to rename your app, you can double-click the target and rename it. This will also have the effect (by default) of updating the bundle identifier.

[image]

Comment: But i want to change "Battery-Status" in our case. I dont want "com.example" to be changed.

Comment: That's okay - just rename the target in the list on the left. Double-click it. If you want your clones to appear as separate apps, the bundle identifier *must* be different - changing the target name will update the last part of the bundle ID for you, by default.

Comment: I can see one of my clone with same bundle name and still get installed independently. thats why i am confused